# Is there a way to change the alpha of the sprite of animation in unity 2d using script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my character transparent in some circumstances, I know I could do that via

```
 GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,0.2f);
```

if it's a single sprite without animation.

But the thing is that it's during an animation, so is there any way to change the sprite sheet's alpha which the animation is using alpha via scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the Color property of the SpriteRenderer, just only change the alpha in keyframes. It should work whether it's a single sprite or multiple sprite since you are animating the color of the renderer.

In the Animation window click Add Property -> Expand SpriteRenderer -> Select + next to Color.

Answer (score 1):

I also wasn't able to change the sprite alpha during sprite animation. But I finally figured it out!

Instead of changing the SpriteRenderer's `color` property, change the `material.color` property instead:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, exactly what I needed.